# Overloading a class containing an explicit constructor with a call to super ( )

Tags: java, constructor

It appears that if a programmer supplied constructor, with a call to super ( )           is used, no other constructor can be invoked in that class ( i.e. it can't be overloaded). Is this normal behavior that is inherent to Java? Why?

```
abstract class Four {
     Four (  ) { }
     Four (int x) { }
    }
class Three extends Four  {
    public Three ( String name) { }
    Three (int t, int y) { }
    }
class Two extends Three {
    Two ( ) { super ( "number");  } 
//  Two (int t, int y) { }  //causes an error when uncommented
    }
class One extends Two {
    public static void main (String [ ] args) {
        new One ( ); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain your question pointing out details from your example?

Comment: When the superclass doesn't have a zero-arg constructor, the subclass constructor(s) must all call `super` explicitly. `Three` doesn't have any zero-arg constructors, so `Two` must call `super` in all of its constructors.

Comment: @ProgrammersBlock the overloaded constructor in class Two causes a compiler error when it is uncommented. @ Jon\ Skeet has provided the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> no other constructor can be invoked in that class ( i.e. it can't be overloaded).

That's not true at all. The problem with your `Two(int t, int y)` constructor is that it doesn't chain to any constructor explicitly, meaning that there's an implicit `super()` call - which fails as there are no parameterless constructors in `Three`<sup>1</sup>. You can fix that in two ways:

- Chain directly to a super constructor

  ```
  Two (int t, int y) {
      super("number");
  }
  ```
- Chain to a constructor in the same class

  ```
  Two (int t, int y) {
      this();
  }
  ```

---

<sup>1</sup> It doesn't have to be parameterless, strictly - if you add a `Three(String... values)` constructor, that's okay. You need to have a constructor that can be invoked with an empty argument list.